# why my value is nill? Dont understand what happen

Tags: lua

I have this.

```
components=require("components")
entity={}
--test---
function entity.test(x,y)
   self ={}
   self.id="test"
   --self.position=components.position(x,y)
   return self
end
return entity
```

In main i have this.

```
entities=require("entity")

function love.load()
test1=entities.test(100,200)
print(test1.id)
end
```

the output is ok, but, when I add another component .

```
 components=require("components")
    entity={}
    --test---
    function entity.test(x,y)
        self ={}
        self.id="test"
        self.position=components.position(x,y)
        return self
    end

    return entity
```

and make another print

```
  entities=require("entity")

function love.load()
    test1=entities.test(100,200)

    print(test1.id)
    print(test1.position.y)

end
```

I got first a nill valur, and then an error because field position is nill. What happen? Thanks in advance.

my component.lua

```
component = {}
--position--
function component.position(x,y)
    self={}
    self.x=x
    self.y=y
    return self
end
return component
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix the problem by declaring your variables `local`, e.g. `local self = {}`.

When you call `entity.test`, that function assigns a new table to the global `self`. It then calls `components.position` which assigns a whole new table to `self`, which never gets the `position` field.